# Xposed, disable pattern required on boot

Tags: xposed-framework, pattern-lock, fingerprint

On my phone, a Nexus 6p, rooted and obviously has Xposed, it asks for my pattern after every single boot, and I can't use my fingerprint. This is extremely annoying, and I dgaf about security. The only reason I even have a pattern is because of the stealing morons in my school.

So I have looked into disabling this, but to no avail. I am trying to find were this is happening in the code but I cannot find it. I am fairly sure it is somewhere in SystemUI, but I don't know exactly where. I have searched in `com.android.systemui.keygaurd`s two classes, and cannot find it. I have searched in every class that looked relevant to my problem.

I absolutely *cannot* find it. Can anybody help me out here please? I want to be able to have my phone boot, and I can automatically unlock it with my fingerprint, but I always have to enter my pattern before I can use my fingerprint.

Thanks!

Comment: Just asking, do you want the pattern *at all*? There is a way to let the fingerprint stay without another "mandatory" PIN/pass/pattern, just not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @AndyYan sorry for the late reply. yes i still want the pattern there, i just dont want to have to enter it on every boot